# Connect a folding door with an armature without deforming the door panels

Tags: animation, armature, bones, workflow, panel

I am building a horizontal folding door with segments that open like a concertina.
Method:

- I first select the door segments then the armature.
- Cntrl + P
- "set parent to" / Armature deform/ with automatic weights
- or with bones?? bones relative??
  [image]
  The attachment works! But when I operate/ opens the armature the door segments are pushed skew and off centre from the bones.  What am I doing wrong?

Any suggestions?

Comment: you should go With Empty Groups, then assign vertices to the groups they are supposed to be part of. With Automatic Weight won't give a good result as there's a risk that a bone influences a part that it is not supposed to influence. But maybe share your file?

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will try it later...where can I upload my blend file if you want to check out my armature?  The second problem is: when the armature is straight, the door segments edges are snug against each other, but when the armature starts to bend, the door segments are pulling away from each other. In real life you will never see this phenomenon....?

Comment: use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: The blender file can be downloaded here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/yJEvKKPP

Answer (score 3):

You *could* rig this sort of bus door arrangement without bones:

[image]

.. a series of hinges, each parented to the previous hinge.

Every hinge has its Z rotation driven by the zero'th, 'master' hinge.. ('Rot Master'). The odd-numbered hinges have -2 * the Z rotation of the master:

[image]

and the even-numbered hinges have +2 * the Z rotation of the master. The drivers can be cut-and-pasted; with care, pairs of doors can be duplicated along with their drivers.

The master's Z rotation is driven by the handle, thus:

[image]

.. where the '20' in the expression is the distance from the handle to the master when fully extended. The handle should have a Limit Location constraint to prevent it going off-axis, below 0, or beyond full extension.

The master and the handle can both be parented to a Root object (The big cube at the left) so the whole rig can be moved around. Doors, or whatever, can be parented to their respective hinges.

[image]

..sort of a cheap, limited, home-made IK.

[image]

Comment: Good one for https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148088/trying-to-rig-a-map too

Comment: @batFINGER ..or that's a good one for this, with a couple of constraints to prevent the doors from going off the rails.. I like VeloFX's solution.. very general. I'd completely forgotten that question!

Comment: Hi Robin, thank you for your idea of showing how to fold the door panels with hinges.  1. Can you tell me where do I access the hinge's driven property tab?  2. Why are the hinges and door "locked"? I want to attach real hinges to the door and modify the door panels. 3. I do not see any constraint setup, but only for the door handle?  4. Is the door hinge an empty cube?

Comment: @Barend Sorry, the linked .blend was locked off as if for an animator. I've replaced the link, it's now to an unlocked version. You still won't be able to rotate the hinges in Z though, because that axis is driven. The simplest way to see that is to N, open the properties panel of the 3D view > 'Item' tab, and have a look at the transforms of the objects You will see the Z rotation of the hinges is purple, showing it's driven. Right-click on the purple field, and select 'Open Drivers Editor'. You may have to move the edge of the Graph section of the panel to see the Driver Expression section.

Comment: Hi Robin, regarding the rigging bus door project:  Are the box hinges empty cubes? How do you hook up the doors to the hinges?  Can I now parent 3d hinges to the cubes and                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        parent the door panels to the 3d hinges? Please advise me if I am missing it.  Many thanks.

Comment: The small-box hinges are box-shaped Empties. The doors are parented to the Empties. You could parent anything else to the hinges, and they would rotate like the doors. You can see parenting in the Outliner, by clicking on the arrows next to  objects, expanding the tree beneath them. The hinges are parented to each other, down the chain to the Rot-Master, which, like the handle, is parented to the big-box-Empty 'Root'. Yes. You could parent mesh-hinges to the empties, and mesh-doors to the mesh-hinges. (Or replace the Empty hinges with hinge+door meshes with the same drivers and parenting)

Answer (score 1):

You must have somehow parented *With Automatic Weight* which has given to some bones influence on some doors that they are not supposed to control. So here is how you could fix the whole thing. First you could have joined all your doors together, but let keep them apart:

- Disable the *Lock Object Modes* option, it will make the interaction between objects and bones easier.

[image]

- Select the armature and enable the *In Front* option so that you can see it through the objects.

[image]

- Select all the doors and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Clear Parent* to deparent them from the armature.

[image]

- Put the *Timeline* cursor at 0 so that the armature is on its *Rest* position (I guess it's the case at frame 0). Select a door, <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the armature, switch it to *Pose* mode, select the bone of this door, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Bone*.

[image]

- It should work:

[image]

Comment: Thank You Moonboots! It works exactly what I wanted to do. You are awesome! Thanks for rolling away this big mountain, I really appreciate all the trouble you took to make this clear, I would have sit stuck for hours trying to figure this out. God Bless you.