# Rigging Folding Door

Tags: rigging, armature

I've got a huge problem with rigging B-folding door. I'm new to rigging and wanted to make an animation of the house that i am modelling now, with nice folding door opening system, and I would like to make it quite realistic, so first is opening the first door, then is folding the next two doors and opened door is slighting to the opening one, etc.

Just like in the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbBmIvi7U0Q&ab_channel=expressbifoldsuk

My problem is that my rig doesn't want to keep my doors in a straight line, when they are closed.

[image: closed door]

Also there is a problem with overlapping part of the doors:

[image]

And here is the file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ycBS4CNLzG3btDfNItJLmSB8nGOrQP4t/view?usp=sharing

Update: 17.08.2021

This is how the doors looks a like where are the closed:

[image]

And when they are folded:

[image]

When they are folded they look perfect, but when the door are closed, joints doesn't want to jump in the right position.

[image]

Comment: you could choose the open door as the default (rest) pose. Also, do you want to be able to control each board or couldn't you control the whole animation with only one bone?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/182714/35559

Comment: Thanks Robin, No this isnt a duplicate, I already know this topic, didnt found any solution to my problem.

Comment: @Zorian Ahhh.. I see.. sorry, didn't read carefully enough.

Answer (score 2):

Well basic idea is quite good already but I would recommend to put smaller bones between big ones that will keep the offset of those doors. Because if you make it like this, 2 doors will have their edge at similar/same location... But if you add another bone just like this (and then you can remove them and set it to keep offset or lock rotation so it wont deform while moving):
[image]

and the second thing I have noticed is that you placed those doors wrong on bones... try to keep it precise for each bone and door. They must be placed perfectly and not with different offsets

Comment: Thanks, I used extra bones, and as it looks fantastic when it is folded, but when the doors are closed the gap between them is huge. is it any chance to fix it ?

Comment: Try to move your bones, dont make them go in the middle of the door but remember that doors have hinges, try to place bones in order where hinges will be, it needs tweaking for sure, maybe some limitations, or something

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm getting closer or not. not sure how to force middle hinge to be where is should be. https://vimeo.com/588241877

Answer (score 2):

I would take what seems to be your original approach, although you needed some parenting and bone rolls fixed:

[image: Pose mode showing door partially open]

I've basically done 3 IK segments,  the *IK bone* target's *IK control* and has a chain length of 2.  Similarly *door 4*'s target is *IK control.001* and *door 2*'s target is *IK control.002*.

Each of the IK control bones is constrained so that it can only move along it's Y axis (which coincides with the world X axis.)

I've left it possible to control each door pair separately, since you didn't say whether you wanted all the doors to unfold at the same time, or for IK control to pull them open in a chain.

In my blend file I've created a 30 frame door open action that you could assign to a controller that does the chain open.  The screen shoot is from individually manipulating the IK controllers.

You'd have to put the doors back in place.  I unparented them to make it easier to work out the armature.

[Blend File](https://blend-exchange.com/b/VzSbMGM8)

I've edited the file to add an action constraint to the IK bones so that open action can be controlled by a single bone.  Here's the new version:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you effort. I would like to open them as a chain, so it looks quite good, hovewer The biggest porblem with this door is that hinges are not in straight line, they are on both sides of the panels. I also updated my questions :)

Comment: The rig in my second blend file will solve your overlapping problem, but it's up to you to place the doors and size the bones properly.  You just have to make sure that the tips of the bones align in a straight line along the x axis

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rig like this:

[image]

Root, bone2, and bone4 have this bone constraint:

[image]

Bone1, 3 and 5 have this constraint:

[image]

From Root to bone5 they are all parented - keep offset.

All bones have "inherited rotation" set to off:

[image]

you can add a "mover" bone so that if you move that bone, the windows open and close, by adding this constraint (transformation) to the controller:

[image]

[image]

[image]

video tutorial: https://youtu.be/07e1NUjYY_8