# confused with copy rotation

Tags: constraints

I have 2 plane on top of each other. Im try to rotate the below plane so that the top plane also move up and rotate in the same angle 45 degree as shown below. I try to add a copy rotation constraint but for me did not work or im confused.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to rotate the base mesh but the top mesh did not rotate just rotate little over there. What else missing or how can i achieve this. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

**I tried this so far** I have deleted the empty and parented the low plane to top and given copy rotation to below. The below plane is rotating in 45 degree but the top does not. Any suggestion.

[image]

Comment: You can set the constraint space to "world". But you want both have constraint on each other? I'm afraid this circular dependency cannot work.

Comment: Concretely, with your file: remove the constraints. Add a third empty. Set again the constraints on the original empties but using the third one as target.

Comment: @lemon i tried this but the top panel not rotation at 45 degree angle https://imgur.com/a/qYszS3C

Comment: Maybe have a look [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/182750/35559)?, or maybe better for your case, the answers [like this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/148529/35559)