# Locking size of a faces in edit mode. Equal faces sizes for mockup

Tags: faces

I would like to make a tri-folded flyer mockup in blender.
When I split a plane for 3 parts and select edge between faces, during editing two faces are changing sizes. Is there any way to drag edges and keep faces in equal sizes?

Is there any lock button, or should I do that with bones? I want to prepare projects in affinity designer and put exual size radio into blender. When I trying edit it in simple edit mode, it causes faces to not having proper project dimensions.

[image: mockup folded flyer]

[image]

Comment: maybe i am stupid, but what did you expect? if you move an edge between faces you will always change their size. It is just math. I hope you want only to rotate them? Or i misunderstood you completely.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're wanting to achieve the hinge-like behavior of a tri-fold flyer. But you describe your efforts at the "Edit" level, because you're talking about moving "edges", and those only exist at that level. Understand that any time you are working on a mesh at the "Edit" level, you are modeling, which means that you are, at that same time, not rigging. The short answer is that, yes, you would want to create bones for that.

Comment: You could rig your flyer so that only rotations of pages about their folds are permitted.  There are some suggestions [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/148088/35559)

Comment: But with rotation we have the same problem. So this is not possible to do that mockup like above in blender with the same size of flyer faces? I must 'fake'  it set it up manually to pretend like it has equal sizes of panels?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to rig a Map](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148088/trying-to-rig-a-map)   As suggested prior by @RobinBetts   See also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/213540/fold-a-plane-then-fold-again/213554?r=SearchResults&s=1|49.9591#213554  re a script to generate a rig on simple meshes where internal edges are folds.

Answer (score 0):

Bones should be kept for animating **characters** and in your case parenting edges to an empty and rotation is enough.